# how to pass a value from attrs.$observe in an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently the console.log(value) outputs the value of 'lat' but if I try and access that value elsewhere in my directive it will not work. I have tried to set a variable equal to attrs.$observe as well as putting the attrs.$observe within a function. In addition for some reason I cannot return the value of data. Any thoughts

```
 angular.module('Ski').directive('mapCanvas', function() {
  function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('lat', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you tried to access it elsewhere in the directive?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this by making some global variable, using `scope` or `var`

**CODE**

```
angular.module('Ski').directive('mapCanvas', function() {
  function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.lat = ''; //or it can be var lat = '';
    attrs.$observe('lat', function(data) {
      scope.lat = data; //or it can be var scope.lat = '';
      console.log(data);
    });
    scope.test = function(){
       //when it gets called
       console.log(scope.lat);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.